# Export JS module without importing it first

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I have the following structure for my JS components:

```
/components
  /Menu
    /Menu.js
    /Menu.test.js
    /index.js
  /MenuItem
    /MenuItem.js
    /MenuItem.test.js
    /index.js
```

The idea being we can have a folder for each component that can contain a test (and possible other files) and then if we just want to import the component we can rely on the use of the `index.js` to handle the directory import without having to reference the class inside the folder direct.

So for example:

Menu.js

```
class Menu extends Component {
  // ... more code ..
}
export default Menu;
```

index.js

```
export default from './Menu';
```

And then it can be used like:

```
import Menu from './components/Menu';
```

However I found that this didn't work and it couldn't find the module...

So to fix this I had to import Menu into the index.js before export:

```
import Menu from './Menu';
export default Menu;
```

But having looked at how other projects have structured their code, I have seen that they are using the former without having to import again...

For example: https://github.com/IBM/carbon-components-react/blob/master/src/components/Breadcrumb/index.js

See how they have exported from the Breadcrumb without having to do the import first... how have they achieved this?

Answer (score 2):

If you check the provided [example](https://github.com/IBM/carbon-components-react/blob/master/package.json#L256), you will see they use 
this [babel plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-plugin-proposal-export-default-from.html).

So you can add one to your babel plugin stack.

Alternatively, you can look into using just `export {default} from "./destination";` form which works as is.